# filename too long when trying to read and write from an array of absolute images

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara-webkit

Have a capybara script that among other things downloads absolute image links.

When trying to write those images to disk I receive an error:

```
File name too long
```

The output also includes a long list of all the image URLs in the array. I think a `gsub` would solve this but I'm not sure which one or exactly how to implement it.

Here are a few sample image URLs that are part of the link array. A suitable substitute name would be `g0377p-xl-3-24c1.jpg` or `g0371b-m-4-6896.jpg` in these examples:

```
http://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/560x560/ced77cb19565515451b3578a3bc0ea5e/g/0/g0377p-xl-3-24c1.jpg
http://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/560x560/ced77cb19565515451b3578a3bc0ea5e/g/0/g0371b-m-4-6896.jpg
```

This is the code:

```
require "capybara/dsl"
require "spreadsheet"
require 'fileutils'
require 'open-uri'

   def initialize
     @excel = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
     @work_list = @excel.create_worksheet
     @row = 0
   end

       imagelink = info.all("//*[@rel='lightbox[rotation]']")
       @work_list[@row, 6] = imagelink.map { |link| link['href'] }.join(', ')
       image = imagelink.map { |link| link['href'] }
       File.basename("#{image}", "w") do |f|
         f.write(open(image).read)
       end
```

Comment: Do you care what the image name actually is? If not, just make up your own name. If it’s too long you just have to make it shorter. That simple. Unless you tell us what a suitable substitute name is we can’t help—and you would already know the answer.

Comment: A suitable substitute name would be: g0377p-xl-3-24c1.jpg or g0371b-m-4-6896.jpg in the examples above; so basically everything after the final forward slash. I guess my question how and where to use the gsub to shorten these on the fly before they are saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`File.basename`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-basename) to get just the filename:

```
uri = 'http://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/560x560/ced77cb19565515451b3578a3bc0ea5e/g/0/g0377p-xl-3-24c1.jpg'
File.basename uri  #=> "g0377p-xl-3-24c1.jpg"
```

Comment: File.basename.open creates wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2) (ArgumentError) ; here is a test url in question: http://www.tomtop.com/clothing-accessories/fashion-ol-women-chiffon-shirt-pleated-front-long-sleeve-button-blouse-tops-g0377.html ; I'm trying to visit and grab all the absolute image urls on that page defined by the selector I have chosen using capybara.

Comment: Ultimately I want to download the images, shorten their name to the base and reference the shortened name in my spreadsheet document.

Comment: @jcuwaz Why are you calling `open`? Nowhere in my answer do I do that. This is just to get the filename, not actually write it.

Comment: Ok that works well; How can I reference that shortened basename in the spreadsheet element that I'm creating in this step: @work_list[@row, 6] = imagelink.map { |link| link['href'] }.join(', ').

Answer (score 0):

There is a real problem with the creation of filename.

```
imagelink = info.all("//*[@rel='lightbox[rotation]']")
```

Will return an array of nodes.

From that you get the `href` value using `map` and save the resulting array in `image`.

Then you try to use that array as the name of the file.